# run windows form on another machine c#?

Tags: c#

Hi i'm new to this c# coding and i've created an application but it on shows up in task manager on another machine and just won run. I've googled and did all that it says with Net framework version and all.

I am thinking maybe it has something to do with my combo box using a file path to get to the external database.

Here is my code with the comcbox:

```
private void combox_txt_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + @"Data Source=C:\Users\Chavoy\Documents\Dougie Company\Application Files\Douglas.Gas.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0;READONLY=FALSE'");

        using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            cn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Cust$] WHERE CustomerName = '" + combox_txt.Text + "' ", cn);
            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                custid_txt.Text = reader["CustomerID"].ToString();
                name_txt.Text = reader["CustomerName"].ToString();
                tel_txt.Text = reader["TelephoneNumber"].ToString();
                address_txt.Text = reader["Address"].ToString();
                sizegas_txt.Text = reader["Size_of_Gas"].ToString();

            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see my path contains my user name and such... but how can i get it to be the other machine username?

Comment: Can't you let the user pick the file with OpenFileDialog?

Comment: yea i did but when loading the combobox to select the sheet name it says its not found because the combox loads the data before the user selects the path

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because Microsoft Access Database Engine is not installed on that machine.

Comment: I even installed that and still no progress.... my friends tried on theirs still no success

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the right .NET framework installed on the computer?

If you are using Visual Studio, you can find the framework version by right clicking your project>Properties>Target Framework.

Comment: So whats the problem exactly? I'm kind of finding it hard to understand your question.

Comment: the problem is that it only appears in task manager when i run it on another machine..... but i've tried all the solutions possible and still no success. Which makes me believe that maybe its the path for the data source as it uses my username as the user and i am wondering if that would cause the problem

Comment: So it appears in task manager but the program doesn't appear on the screen. If you are using forms, maybe you aren't telling it to open or you have put some code that is telling the form to close.

Comment: I've managed to fix it with app config. There was a problem with the file path causing it not to run.

Comment: <appSettings>
    <add key="File" value="C:\Douglas Gas and Grocery\Application Files\Douglas.Gas.xlsx" />